# How to deserialize an object from byte[] where byte[] represents an object of a class that is loaded over a network?

Tags: java

How to deserialize an object from byte[] where byte[] represents an object of a class that is loaded over a network?

I have the following `Hello.java` file

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Hello implements Serializable {

    public Integer hello = 5;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(sayHello());
    }

    public static String sayHello() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

Its compiled into `Hello.class` and stored at `/tmp/test`

Below is an example similar to the Application I am working on.

```
public class Util {

    public static byte[] serializeObject(Object object) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
        objectOutputStream.close();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    public static Object deserializeObject1(byte[] serializedObject) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedObject);
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
        Object object = objectInputStream.readObject();
        objectInputStream.close();
        byteArrayInputStream.close();
        return object;
    }

    public static Object deserializeObject2(byte[] byteArray) {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        ObjectInput input = null;
        try {
            input = new ObjectInputStream(bis){
                @Override protected Class<?> resolveClass(final ObjectStreamClass desc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
                    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                    if (cl == null)  return super.resolveClass(desc);
                    return Class.forName(desc.getName(), false, cl);
                }
            };
            return input.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                bis.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main application

```
public class Dynamic {

     private ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         File myFile=new File("/tmp/test/");

         try {
            URLClassLoader  cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{myFile.toURI().toURL()});
            Class klazz = cl.loadClass("Hello");
            Object object = klazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            System.out.println(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(object)); //works
            byte[] serObjectbytes  = Util.serializeObject(object);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(serObjectbytes)); // works
            Object deserializeObject = Util.deserializeObject1(serObjectbytes); //fails
            Object deserializeObject2 = Util.deserializeObject2(serObjectbytes); // also fails
  System.out.println(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(deserializeObject));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException esx) {
            esx.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

}
```

so both `Util.deserializeObject1` and `Util.deserializeObject1` fails with `ClassNotFoundException ex` I understand I am trying just deserialize bunch of bytes and Java class loader wouldn't have any idea of where the `Hello.class` unless I `defineClass` again, however, my goal here is to deserialize into a `Hello` object and repopulate to the same state as it was in before serialization. How do I do that?

Comment: Deserializing inherently creates a new instance. When serializing and deserializing Java objects between JVMs, both JVMs must be aware of the Class.

Comment: Sure can it create a new instance and repopulate the same state the object was in before serialization? I just don't want to lose the state before serialization (other words the values of instance variables) different instances is ok. so I edited my question accordingly

Comment: Yes, serializing will persist all non-`transient`, serializable instance fields which will be restored upon deserialization. But in order for Java to reconstruct the object it must know about the `Class` of the object.

Comment: The class name is `Hello` but I am not sure how to get it working? I tried `urlClassloader.defineClass` but still couldn't create an object since I still get `ClassNotFoundException` looks like something is up with my classLoaders and I am not an expert in classLoaders.

Comment: I want to be able to define a class from `byte[]` which is equal to `byte[] serbytes  = Util.serializeObject(object)`

Comment: I want to go from `byte[]` to `object` in this case

Comment: You can't define a class from the bytes of a serialized **instance**. You need the bytes of the actual **class**. The serialized stream is just enough of a description to rebuild the object later. So, if you want to create a class and send it to some remote JVM, you need to send the bytes that would be in the `.class` file in order to define it.

Comment: yeah figured it out. it works now!